# Nasm using local Labels as offsets

Tags: data-structures, label, structure, nasm, local

Hi can you use a local Label as an offset into a structure ?

Like if i write it like this:

```
GENERIC_HEADER:
.NAME: db "TEST_NAME",0
.SIZE: db 0xff
.OTHER_STUFF: dq 0xff00ff00ff00ff00
```

can i SOMEHOW use them like this:

```
start:
mov si, GENERIC_HEADER
mov al, [si.SIZE]
mov rax, [si.OTHER_STUFF]
```

Thanks for any answers !

Comment: Take a look here: https://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc4.html#section-4.11.10

Comment: @rkhb thanks exactly what I was searching for !